# Dokuwiki - IndexMenu Plugin: How to create pages meaningfully?

Tags: plugins, indexing, dokuwiki

I've started using IndexMenu to implement an automatically updating index for my wiki. Now, I have implemented indexes on all front pages of my (sub)namespaces, but have run in to the problem of how to meaningfully add pages at this point.

To me, the whole idea of creating pages in a wiki was to create an empty link on an index page, follow the link and fill it with content. Now that the indexing is being done by the plugin, I wonder how I can still create pages within the wiki backend without resorting to create the pages in the actual folder structure.

Am I just completely missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I'm having trouble understanding the question, you can still create pages by creating/following a link - but you might find this plugin useful:

https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:addnewpage

If you install it and add {{NEWPAGE}} to your sidebar.txt, users will be able to create a page anywhere they have permission for.